# Next.js Image Styling through css

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have a next JS component here:

```js
import styles from '../styles/Navbar.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'

export const Navbar = () => {
    <div>
        <Image className={styles["navbar-home-icon"]} src="/vercel.svg"/>
    </div>
}
```

`Navbar.module.css`:

```css
.navbar-home-icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

The problem is, I can't use the `navbar-home-icon` class to set the width and height of the image. Not even the border shows up. It throws this error

> Error: Image with src "/vercel.svg" must use "width" and "height" properties o
> r "layout='fill'" property

I know the css file is being detected because this is what shows up in the developer view:[image]

If I add in `height` and `width` properties into the tag itself, the image shows up.

I understand what the error is, but how do I control the width/height/any other property through my css file? - Instead of explicitly declaring them inside the Image tag?

Comment: As stated in the error message, pass the prop ```layout=fill```. And then you can set height and width in your css.

Comment: This doesn't work, the image just fills the entire screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put Image inside div and put the following props on the Image:

```
<div className="div-class">
   <Image src=“/vercel.svg” layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. The image becomes supersized and only part of it is visible.

Comment: ok now put position: relative on the .div-class

Comment: The image fills itself inside the box and doesn't stay inside the bounds of the div

Comment: did you put objectFit="cover" as one of the props?

Comment: @Helix [cover vs contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: This is exactly what I have
```<div className={styles["navbar-home-icon"]}>
    <Image className={styles["navbar-home-icon"]} src="/vercel.svg" layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'd have to see an image of what it looks like, but yeah try "contain" instead of "cover".